# How to search for words that contains upper case letters except a few words in Notepad++ Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given a sql query with some columns that have upper case letters, how can I search for words that contain a upper case letter but not SQL keywords, for example:

```
SELECT ... ,
    table1.thisColumn AS column,
    ...
    FROM table1
```

I've tried without success to build something like this:

```
(?!AS+FROM+LEFT+JOIN+ON)[A-Z]{2,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to note about your existing regex.

1. The "or" operator in the exception-list should be a `|` and not a `+`. The `+` will be treated as an actual character whereas the `|` will tell the regex engine "left" *or* "right", as you want in this case.
2. To match a full-word that contains at least one upper-case letter, you actually need to check for the lower-case letters as well - but "require" at least one upper-case letter.

I've come up with the following:

```
(?:^|\.|[\t ])(?!AS|FROM|LEFT|JOIN|ON)([a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

I tested this against your sample query and also added other random SQL to it (such as an expanded field list, `WHERE` clause, etc.). It successfully found each word that contained at least one capital letter and was not in the list of keywords to ignore.

If you're using this to just "search" via `Find Next` or `Find All in Opened|Current Documents`, it will highlight the matching word and a preceding `.` or whitespace character(s).

If you're using this to "replace", the matched word (without the preceding `.` or whitespace character(s)) can be used/accessed via the `\1` match.

Regex Explained:

```
(?:                         # non-matching group;
                            # a "word" is required to be preceeded by one of the following
    ^                       # beginning of line
    |\.                     # period
    |[\t ]                  # tab or space;
                            # note: we don't use the \s here because a newline will break notepadd++'s "find all" feature
)

(?!AS|FROM|LEFT|JOIN|ON)    # list of words to ignore

(                           # group to match
    [a-z0-9]*               # word can start with lowercase a-z or 0-9
    [A-Z]                   # required uppercase letter
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+            # word can end with lowercase/uppercase a-z or 0-9
)
```

You'll also want to add in any missing SQL keywords (if needed), or other allowed characters in the "words can have these characters" list.

Comment: Can you verify that's correct? I've tried it with some examples here (including the one given, and it's not matching anything). This part of the regex ([a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+) is doing fine, but when I try adding the first part it matches nothing.

Comment: @Vandell Just tested it again using your example copy/pasted (both your example, and the regex) and it matches perfectly. I'm using Notepadd++ v6.1.2, if that makes a difference (I'll update to the most recent version now and re-test to make sure).

Comment: @Vandell Updated to v6.1.5 and it still works fine with the full regex.

Comment: I'm using 5.9.8, let me try updating it

Comment: @Vandell That should fix it (hopefully); According to their changelog, PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) began support in v6.0

Comment: Oh yeeah! It's working, thank your for your time newfurniturey.